# Google Blogger domain name change

Tags: blogger

I have changed my blogger domain name. The old address is still showing for online searches. Will this revert to my new domain address over time?

Comment: Did you do redirects from the old domain to the new domain?

Comment: The redirect domain option is visible on my settings page but frozen out so I can't set it to redirect???

Comment: This question is about a domain name change in Blogger.   Blogger does not offer a cross-domain re-direct feature.

Comment: Are you using a domain name you own, or are you using a blogspot.com address? Do you have inbound links and organic search visitors, or is the site relatively new?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will - eventually, as Google gets around to indexing your new site, and de-indexing your old one.  It may take quite  a while though.

If your old domain name was a custom one, then you may be able to use redirection features provided by the domain-name provider to redirect visitors to the new domain.   Although this isn't available if you purchased the domain from Google via Blogger.